# Is there a way to forcibly terminate touch scrolling in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a [page of image tiles](https://new.isomizu.com/art) that transitions into an image viewer when a tile is clicked. When the theater is closed, it automatically scrolls down to last viewed image's tile. One of the options for closing the theater is swiping down on mobile. However, if the user keeps moving their finger across the screen after swiping down, the browser prevents the script from scrolling the page.

Is there a way to forcibly cancel the user's touch or otherwise allow `.scrollIntoView` to override user scrolling?

Here's a quick example I threw together. The script attempts to smooth scroll the page to the last tile every 2 seconds, but if the user scrolls during the animation, it gets canceled.

```js
setInterval(() => {

  document.getElementById("target").scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    inline: "center"
  });
  document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = "Scrolling..."
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = ""
  }, 500);

}, 2000);
```

```css
#container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.tile {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#indicator {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile" id="target"></div>

  <div id="indicator"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you should tap into a gesture library like Swiper instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I can't really justify switching everything over to a library over one minor issue, and I'm not sure if that'd solve the root problem of the user being able to override the `scrollIntoView` event.

Comment: It kinda feels like in this case it's a matter of the UI not fitting how users use phones: rather than scrolling, set the offsetY to just instantly be where you need to be?

Comment: I ended up finding a duct tape solution while fixing an issue with overscrolling. If I apply `overflow: hidden` to the document body while the image viewer is open, and then remove it after the closing animations are finished, the user is unable to interrupt the scrolling.

Comment: Nice. Sounds like you probably want to write that up as an answer.